# Versioning for Core Library and Extension Libraries

Tags: c#, versioning, ninject, backwards-compatibility

The Ninject project consists of the Ninject Core library and lot (~17) of extension libraries.

Currently, Ninject and its Extension Libraries all have the same Major.Minor number. The next release of Ninject core will be backward compatible thus increasing the minor number is the correct action. At least one of the extension libraries will not be backward compatible. In this case the correct action would be to increase the major number. But this will put the core and extensions out of sync.

The question is which option do you consider the best that will cause the least confusion:

1. Correctly increase the major number with the advantage that the version number reflects the backwards incompatibility and the disadvantage that the core and the extensions are put out of sync so that it won't be easy to to tell what matches anymore.
2. Keep the major number for the extension and increase only the minor number. With the advantage that the numbers are the same and it is easy to tell what matches. But the dsiadvantage that the number doesn't reflect the backward incompatibility.
3. Increase the major number of everything. With the advantage that the numbers are the same. But the disadvantage that the core and several extensions have the major number increased even though they are backward compatible.

Or can you think of another better option?

Comment: I think [programmers.se] is a better place for this question, but my question to you is this: Do you consider the version number of the core library to be strongly related to the version number of the extensions?

Comment: Did the extension library in question change at all? As in: did the code in that extension library change, at all?

Comment: The extensions are normally built for the latest core version and use some new functionality and therefore not run with an older one. Old extenisons on the other hand should run with a newer core version as long as it is backward compatible.

Comment: Some extensions changed but are backward compatible, some changed breaking compatibility and some are unchanged.

Comment: I guess my main beef is this: If only the core NInject library changed, and you say it is backwards compatible, then there is no way an extension to it should *become* incompatible because of the updated core library (that's what backwards compatible means), unless that extension changed as well. So if you have tied the extensions tightly into the core, project-wise, then you have a rather strong dependency that you're going to fight hard to get rid of.

Comment: I think you didn't understand correctly. By compatibility I mean against the consumer of the them (The application that uses Ninject and some of its extensions) and not between core and extension.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would go with the last option, I don't think increasing major version number means that the backwards compatibility has been broken explicitly, there are many cases that a version number of a product has increased without it breaking backwards compatibility, take a look at .NET for example version number has been increased over the years from 1 to 4 with almost no breakage across all the versions.